# git find parent direcitory from a child

Tags: git, github

i have cloned a directory using git clone commnad and following are the commands that are followed

```
     git clone git_main git_clone
     cd git_clone
     ls 
     sys info ff bin .git
     ff has the following directory structure   
     ff/tt/gg/a.txt 
     cd ff/tt/gg
     gg>
```

Now from gg how will i know whats my main parent i.e, git_clone directory is there any git commnad or  how can i find the parent .git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git rev-parse --git-dir
```

This tells you where the `.git` directory is.

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

This tells you where the root of your working tree is.